# Alamofire 5.4 upload progress issue

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am working on an app where I need to upload images and everything was working until I updated Alamofire to version 5.4.2 where I had a problem with upload progress.

The progress is showing 2 values.

```
func uploadImage(url: String, image: UIImage, params: [String: String], header: HTTPHeaders) {
    
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (mp) in
        if let imgData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
            mp.append(imgData, withName: "image[0]", fileName: "\(UUID().uuidString).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
        
        for (key, value) in params {
            mp.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
        
    }, to: url, method: .post, headers: header)
    
    .uploadProgress { (progress) in
        let frac = progress.fractionCompleted
        let percent = Int(frac * 100)
        SVProgressHUD.showProgress(Float(frac), status: "\(percent)%")
        print("\(percent)%")
    }
    
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("success !!")
            
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

> 12%
>
> 100%

Is there any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Fix what? There is no guarantee of any particular progress values. If your upload finishes quickly you will only see two, or even just one progress update.

Comment: Thanks Jon Shier
But it was working fine with version 4.9.1
Now when it reaches 100% it feels like it waits for the upload to actually complete and it takes several seconds

Comment: Isn't it possible the upload is complete and the server takes time to respond? If you investigate further you should be able to narrow down what's really going on.